# How do I set up EF Core to cascade delete on a one to one relationship?

Tags: entity-framework, one-to-one, cascading-deletes

I'm trying to get cascade delete working for a one to one relationship in EF Core 5. When I delete a ParentTable entity, I want the associated ChildTable entity to be deleted from the database as well.

The database is set up in this way:

**ParentTable**

- Id
- ChildId (FK, unique)

**ChildTable**

- Id

And configure it in EF Core for the Parent entity this way:

```
            builder.HasOne(o => o.ChildTable)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey<ParentTable>("ChildId")
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

When I remove a ParentTable entity from the context, it does not also remove the ChildTable.  I must be missing something, but I don't know what that is.

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When writing `HasForeignKey<ParentTable>("ChildId")` you specify the  to be the dependent entity. Therefore the relationship between the entities have been reversed from what you want it to be. Try switching it to something similar to:

```
builder.HasOne(x => x.ChildTable).WithOne().HasForeignKey<ChildTable>(x => x.ForeignKey).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Casacade)
```

Check this link out if you want the Microsoft's documentation on the topic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#one-to-one

Comment: Does this mean I have to have the FK on the ChildTable in the database?  I was hoping to avoid that, since you couldn't tell at a glance when looking at the ParentTable if it had an associated child element or not without doing an inner join.

Comment: Correct, this would put the FK in the ChildTable